# Raspberry Pi 4: Error: Cannot find module 'sqlite3'

Tags: node.js, sqlite, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, node-sqlite3

Status of sqlite3 installation on my Raspberry Pi 4 B when queried from the terminal:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sqlite3 --version
3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06 bd49a8271d650fa89e446b42e513b595a717b9212c91dd384aab871fc1d0alt1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

For me it is confirmation that installation is complete. Also, I did not do any thing like creating a table or etc. I just installed it. Now I am trying to access it.

My code:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
```

Response:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'sqlite3'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
```

Don't know why it says cannot find `sqlite3` when terminal clearly shows its installation and ability to access sqlite3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [binary executable named `sqlite3`](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) and the [Node.js module named `sqlite3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) are not the same thing.

You need to [install the Node.js module](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-locally) to use the Node.js module.

Comment: I appreciate your information. I did not know there are different sqlite3 versions or packages. Can you please tell me how were you able to tell that I actually installed binary executable named Sqlite3 ? Infact I installed the `sqlite3` by typing this in terminal `sudo apt install sqlite3` which is a standard for `node.js sqlite3` installation. But I am still curious what is wrong?

Comment: "Can you please tell me how were you able to tell that I actually installed binary executable named Sqlite3" — You typed `sqlite3` on the command line and the program ran.

Comment: "Infact I installed the sqlite3 by typing this in terminal sudo apt install sqlite3 which is a standard for node.js sqlite3 installation" — No. That's how you install the sqlite3 binary executable. It has nothing to do with Node.js at all.

Comment: "But I am still curious what is wrong?" — You installed the wrong thing. You are trying to `require` a Node.js module. You have not installed that module.

Comment: My mistake and bad. I just realized. It is actually `sudo npm install sqlite3`.

Comment: You should not need to use `sudo` to install a module from NPM. You should be installing it in  your project directory (created with `mkdir my-project; cd my-project; npm init`) as a normal user. Leave `sudo` to tasks that really need superuser access (i.e. system administration).

Comment: This is another big lesson. All the packages I am installing, I am just using `sudo` without any thought. But I appreciate this and thanks for educating me on this.

Comment: does the `my_script.js` where I import the `const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();` have to be physically in the same directory or sub directory of the `my-project` where the `npm sqlite3` is installed?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's rather the point of having a project. It encapsulates all the dependencies *for that project*.

Comment: Hurray! success and I could successfully import it in my script. Oh! Man, I really appreciate your help and support. I have been struggling with this for hours.